# Bacula backup - Cannot find any appendable volumes

Tags: bacula

I try to run full backup at my backup server.It show like this.

```
02-Sep 12:44 backup-sd JobId 5468: Job KLDC01Backup.2016-09-02_02.00.00_20 is waiting. 
Cannot find any appendable volumes.
Please use the "label" command to create a new Volume for:
    Storage:      "LocalDisk-KLDC01" (/backup/kldc01)
    Pool:         KLDC01
    Media type:   File6
```

Not sure what happen. Since I have not touched any configuration files.

This is my director configuration file.

```
#
# Default Bacula Director Configuration file
#
#  For Bacula release 5.0.2 (28 April 2010) -- debian 6.0.3
#

Director {                            # define myself
  Name = backup-dir
  DIRport = 9101                # where we listen for UA connections
  QueryFile = "/etc/bacula/scripts/query.sql"
  WorkingDirectory = "/var/lib/bacula"
  PidDirectory = "/var/run/bacula"
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 1
  Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"         # Console password
#  Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  Messages = Daemon
  DirAddress = 0.0.0.0
}

# Generic catalog service
Catalog {
  Name = MyCatalog
  dbname = "bacula"; dbuser = "bacula"; dbpassword = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

# Clients Config File
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/clients.conf

# Storage Config File
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/storage.conf

# Pools Config File
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/pools.conf

# Schedules Config File
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/schedules.conf

# Messages Config File
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/messages.conf

# Job Defaults Config File
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/jobs/jobdefs.conf           # Default parameters that jobs will include

# Job Config Files
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/jobs/catalogbackup.conf     # Bacula Catalog Backup - Daily Incremental
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/jobs/backup.conf            # Backup this server - Daily
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/jobs/dominus.conf           # Dominus Backup - Daily
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/jobs/ciku.conf              # Ciku Backup - Daily
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/jobs/lychee.conf            # Lychee Backup - Daily
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/jobs/kldc01.conf            # KLDC01 Backup - Daily
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/jobs/apricot.conf           # Apricot Backup - Daily
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/jobs/fig.conf               # Fig Backup - Daily

# Default Restore Resource
@/etc/bacula/conf.d/jobs/restore.conf           # Default Restore Resource

#
# Restricted console used by tray-monitor to get the status of the director
#

Console {
  Name = backup-mon
  Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  CommandACL = status, .status
}
```

This is my bacula-sd.conf file

```
#
# Default Bacula Storage Daemon Configuration file
#
#  For Bacula release 5.0.2 (28 April 2010) -- debian 6.0.3
#
# You may need to change the name of your tape drive
#   on the "Archive Device" directive in the Device
#   resource.  If you change the Name and/or the
#   "Media Type" in the Device resource, please ensure
#   that dird.conf has corresponding changes.
#

Storage {                             # definition of myself
  Name = backup-sd
  SDPort = 9103                  # Director's port
  WorkingDirectory = "/var/lib/bacula"
  Pid Directory = "/var/run/bacula"
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 20
  SDAddress = 0.0.0.0
}

#
# List Directors who are permitted to contact Storage daemon
#
Director {
  Name = backup-dir
  Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

#
# Restricted Director, used by tray-monitor to get the
#   status of the storage daemon
#
Director {
  Name = backup-mon
  Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  Monitor = yes
}

#
# Note, for a list of additional Device templates please
#  see the directory /examples/devices
# Or follow the following link:
#  http://bacula.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bacula/trunk/bacula/examples/devices/
#

#
# Devices supported by this Storage daemon
# To connect, the Director's bacula-dir.conf must have the
#  same Name and MediaType.
#


# Backup To Local disks /dev/md0 or "/backup" as it is labelled.
# Simply a 2x 2TB RAID1 Array.


Device {
  Name = LocalDisk-Backup
  Media Type = File1
  Archive Device = /backup/backup
  LabelMedia = yes;                   # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
  Random Access = Yes;
  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
  RemovableMedia = no;
  AlwaysOpen = no;
}

Device {
  Name = LocalDisk-Ciku
  Media Type = File4
  Archive Device = /backup/ciku
  LabelMedia = yes;                   # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
  Random Access = Yes;
  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
  RemovableMedia = no;
  AlwaysOpen = no;
}

Device {
  Name = LocalDisk-Lychee
  Media Type = File5
  Archive Device = /backup/lychee
  LabelMedia = yes;                   # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
  Random Access = Yes;
  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
  RemovableMedia = no;
  AlwaysOpen = no;
}

Device {
  Name = LocalDisk-Apricot
  Media Type = File7
  Archive Device = /backup/apricot
  LabelMedia = yes;                   # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
  Random Access = Yes;
  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
  RemovableMedia = no;
  AlwaysOpen = no;
}

Device {
  Name = LocalDisk-Fig
  Media Type = File8
  Archive Device = /backup/fig
  LabelMedia = yes;                   # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
  Random Access = Yes;
  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
  RemovableMedia = no;
  AlwaysOpen = no;
}

# ---- Windows Machines ----

Device {
  Name = LocalDisk-Dominus
  Media Type = File3
  Archive Device = /backup/dominus
  LabelMedia = yes;                   # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
  Random Access = Yes;
  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
  RemovableMedia = no;
  AlwaysOpen = no;
}

Device {
  Name = LocalDisk-KLDC01
  Media Type = File6
  Archive Device = /backup/kldc01
  LabelMedia = yes;                   # lets Bacula label unlabeled media
  Random Access = Yes;
  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
  RemovableMedia = no;
  AlwaysOpen = no;
}





# An autochanger device with two drives
#
#Autochanger {
#  Name = Autochanger
#  Device = Drive-1
#  Device = Drive-2
#  Changer Command = "/etc/bacula/scripts/mtx-changer %c %o %S %a %d"
#  Changer Device = /dev/sg0
#}

#Device {
#  Name = Drive-1                      #
#  Drive Index = 0
#  Media Type = DLT-8000
#  Archive Device = /dev/nst0
#  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
#  AlwaysOpen = yes;
#  RemovableMedia = yes;
#  RandomAccess = no;
#  AutoChanger = yes
#  #
#  # Enable the Alert command only if you have the mtx package loaded
#  # Note, apparently on some systems, tapeinfo resets the SCSI controller
#  #  thus if you turn this on, make sure it does not reset your SCSI
#  #  controller.  I have never had any problems, and smartctl does
#  #  not seem to cause such problems.
#  #
#  Alert Command = "sh -c 'tapeinfo -f %c |grep TapeAlert|cat'"
#  If you have smartctl, enable this, it has more info than tapeinfo
#  Alert Command = "sh -c 'smartctl -H -l error %c'"
#}

#Device {
#  Name = Drive-2                      #
#  Drive Index = 1
#  Media Type = DLT-8000
#  Archive Device = /dev/nst1
#  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
#  AlwaysOpen = yes;
#  RemovableMedia = yes;
#  RandomAccess = no;
#  AutoChanger = yes
#  # Enable the Alert command only if you have the mtx package loaded
#  Alert Command = "sh -c 'tapeinfo -f %c |grep TapeAlert|cat'"
#  If you have smartctl, enable this, it has more info than tapeinfo
#  Alert Command = "sh -c 'smartctl -H -l error %c'"
#}

#
# A Linux or Solaris LTO-2 tape drive
#
#Device {
#  Name = LTO-2
#  Media Type = LTO-2
#  Archive Device = /dev/nst0
#  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
#  AlwaysOpen = yes;
#  RemovableMedia = yes;
#  RandomAccess = no;
#  Maximum File Size = 3GB
## Changer Command = "/etc/bacula/scripts/mtx-changer %c %o %S %a %d"

## Changer Device = /dev/sg0
## AutoChanger = yes
#  # Enable the Alert command only if you have the mtx package loaded
## Alert Command = "sh -c 'tapeinfo -f %c |grep TapeAlert|cat'"
## If you have smartctl, enable this, it has more info than tapeinfo
## Alert Command = "sh -c 'smartctl -H -l error %c'"
#}

#
# A Linux or Solaris LTO-3 tape drive
#
#Device {
#  Name = LTO-3
#  Media Type = LTO-3
#  Archive Device = /dev/nst0
#  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
#  AlwaysOpen = yes;
#  RemovableMedia = yes;
#  RandomAccess = no;
#  Maximum File Size = 4GB
## Changer Command = "/etc/bacula/scripts/mtx-changer %c %o %S %a %d"
## Changer Device = /dev/sg0
## AutoChanger = yes
#  # Enable the Alert command only if you have the mtx package loaded
## Alert Command = "sh -c 'tapeinfo -f %c |grep TapeAlert|cat'"
## If you have smartctl, enable this, it has more info than tapeinfo
## Alert Command = "sh -c 'smartctl -H -l error %c'"
#
#
# A Linux or Solaris LTO-4 tape drive
#
#Device {
#  Name = LTO-4
#  Media Type = LTO-4
#  Archive Device = /dev/nst0
#  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
#  AlwaysOpen = yes;
#  RemovableMedia = yes;
#  RandomAccess = no;
#  Maximum File Size = 5GB
## Changer Command = "/etc/bacula/scripts/mtx-changer %c %o %S %a %d"
## Changer Device = /dev/sg0
## AutoChanger = yes
#  # Enable the Alert command only if you have the mtx package loaded
## Alert Command = "sh -c 'tapeinfo -f %c |grep TapeAlert|cat'"
## If you have smartctl, enable this, it has more info than tapeinfo
## Alert Command = "sh -c 'smartctl -H -l error %c'"
#}
#  Archive Device = /dev/nsa1
#  AutomaticMount = yes;               # when device opened, read it
#  AlwaysOpen = yes
#  Offline On Unmount = no
#  Hardware End of Medium = no
#  BSF at EOM = yes
#  Backward Space Record = no
#  Fast Forward Space File = no
#  TWO EOF = yes
#  If you have smartctl, enable this, it has more info than tapeinfo
#  Alert Command = "sh -c 'smartctl -H -l error %c'"
#}
#
#
# Send all messages to the Director,
# mount messages also are sent to the email address
#
Messages {
  Name = Standard
  director = backup-dir = all
}
```

This is my /etc/bacula/conf.d/pools.conf

```
# Pool Configuration File

# Default Pool
#Pool {
#  Name = Default
#  Pool Type = Backup
#  Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle Volumes
#  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes
#  Volume Retention = 365 days         # one month
#}

# Local Disk Storage Pools

#
#
# Linux Client Pools
#
#

Pool {
  Name = Backup
  Pool Type = Backup
  LabelFormat = "backup-"
  Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle Volumes
  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes
  Volume Retention = 30 days         # one month
  Maximum Volume Bytes = 50G          # Limit Volume size to something reasonable
  Maximum Volumes = 2              # Limit number of Volumes in Pool
}

Pool {
  Name = Ciku
  Pool Type = Backup
  LabelFormat = "ciku-"
  Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle Volumes
  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes
  Volume Retention = 30 days         # one month
  Maximum Volume Bytes = 300G          # Limit Volume size to something reasonable
  Maximum Volumes = 2              # Limit number of Volumes in Pool
}


Pool {
  Name = Lychee
  Pool Type = Backup
  LabelFormat = "lychee-"
  Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle Volumes
  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes
  Volume Retention = 30 days         # one month
  Maximum Volume Bytes = 400G          # Limit Volume size to something reasonable
  Maximum Volumes = 2              # Limit number of Volumes in Pool
}

Pool {
  Name = Apricot
  Pool Type = Backup
  LabelFormat = "apricot-"
  Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle Volumes
  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes
  Volume Retention = 30 days         # one month
  Maximum Volume Bytes = 500G          # Limit Volume size to something reasonable
  Maximum Volumes = 2              # Limit number of Volumes in Pool
}

Pool {
  Name = Fig
  Pool Type = Backup
  LabelFormat = "fig-"
  Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle Volumes
  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes
  Volume Retention = 30 days         # one month
  Maximum Volume Bytes = 200G          # Limit Volume size to something reasonable
  Maximum Volumes = 2              # Limit number of Volumes in Pool
}

# Windows Pools

Pool {
  Name = Dominus
  Pool Type = Backup
  LabelFormat = "dominus-"
  Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle Volumes
  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes
  Volume Retention = 30 days         # one month
  Maximum Volume Bytes = 500G          # Limit Volume size to something reasonable
  Maximum Volumes = 1              # Limit number of Volumes in Pool
}

Pool {
  Name = KLDC01
  Pool Type = Backup
  LabelFormat = "kldc01-"
  Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle Volumes
  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes
  Volume Retention = 30 days         # one month
  Maximum Volume Bytes = 500G          # Limit Volume size to something reasonable
  Maximum Volumes = 2              # Limit number of Volumes in Pool
}
```

I did some research and it related with Hard disk space issue.And now I already clear some space for it.This is the hard disk space for my server.

```
/dev/md0                                               ext3      1.8T  1.1T  629G  64% /backup
```

Comment: @Rahul..how to purge it at bconsole?..Please advice...

Comment: @Rahul may i know which config files?

Comment: @Rahul..sorry...ok done...

Comment: how much free disk space is available ? do `df -hT`

Comment: @Rahul..edited...